# TraMineR refseq

Tags: r, traminer

I use the function seqdist from package TraMineR.

First I calculate on 2 trajectories in seq.all  :

```
seqdist(seq.all[1:2,], method="OM", indel=1.1, sm=couts)


         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  0.00000 46.91843
[2,] 46.91843  0.00000
```

So the distance between this trajectories seems to be 46.91843.

But when I use the argument refseq :

```
seqdist(seq.all[1,], method="OM", indel=1.1, sm=couts,refseq = seq.all[2,])

[1] 60.32636
```

Now the distance between this trajectories seems to be 60.32636.

What is the trick ?

Comment: Please provide the matrix `couts` and the two sequences.

Answer (score 2):

You get the distances from all sequences to one of the sequence of the considered sequence object by passing the index of the sequence as `refseq` argument. So, you could get the distance between your two sequences with

```
seqdist(seq.all, method="OM", sm=couts, indel=1.1, refseq=2)[1]
```

Nevertheless, your code should work too and should provide the same value.

This is a bug that may occur when the refseq sequence is passed as a sequence object. We will fix it and make the new version available in the next days on R-Forge.

Comment: Thank you Gilbert !